# form to email, the form is not posting to my mail

Tags: php, html, email

```
<?php 
// code goes here
$to = ""; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$name = $_POST['name'];
$one = $_POST['one'];
$two = $_POST['two'];
$three = $_POST['three'];
$four = $_POST['four'];
$subject = "Form submission";
$subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
$message = $name . " " . $one . " " . $two . " " . $three . " " . $four . " " . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
$message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
echo "Thankyou for your feedback " . $name;

?>
```

***EMAIL:**                             **Name***(optional)***:***

**I am very satisfied with the way the company is performing its tasks to its clients.**

Strongly agree Agree Neutral Disagree Strongly disagree

**How satisfied are you with the company services?**

Not at all SatisfiedSomehow Satisfied Satisfied Very Satisfied Delighted

**How often do you use our services?**

Once a yearDaily Weekly Monthly Every 2 to 3 months Do not use

p>**Based on your awareness of our Service, is it better, the same, or worse than
other companies?**

Much betterBetter About the same Worse Much Worse

Comment: Can you show the code, please?

Comment: the html code? @DieterMeemken

Comment: Is `$to` really empty or have you just removed the address due to privacy?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? How can we help?

Comment: i removed it for privacy @Twinfriends

Comment: there is no any error message in the error log @DieterMeemken

Comment: i am wondering why it is not submitting to the $to email @DieterMeemken

Comment: I have updated its html can you please help me out  @Максим Владимирович

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to send it using this function:

**back.php**

Here is some input data:

```
$to      = $_POST['to'];
$subject = $_POST['subj'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from    = 'robot@' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Here is the function:

```
function send_mail($to, $from, $subject, $message) {
  $headers = ['From: ' . $from, 'Reply-To: ' . $from, 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()]
  return mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
}
```

Here is how it can be used:

```
send_mail($to, $from, $subject, $message);
```

**index.html**
Here is the form:

```
<form action="back.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="To" name="to">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subj">
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: If it's didn't helps, can you please provide var_dump of each of your variables. Second: check you target email. Third: check "Spam" at your inbox.

Comment: would you please do me a code that submits data of a form, because av done som much and still no results, you can use the php above to guide you on the varialbes  @Максим Владимирович